# How to read images from a list

Tags: python, list, numpy, opencv, image-processing

Hi I have a set of images stored as list items and I want to read the images one by one and perform some operations on it. I cannot figure out how to iterate through each image item in the list. I can read them explicitly from a folder using `cv2.imread` but I want to make use of the list element in which they are stored.

I am trying to read the aligned images which I have stored in a list element "align". The subroutine I have used for image alignment is this:

```
def stackImagesECC(file_list):
    M = np.eye(3, 3, dtype=np.float32)

    first_image = None
    stacked_image = None
    align = []



    for file in file_list:
        image = cv2.imread(file,1).astype(np.float32) / 255
        print(file)
        if first_image is None:
            # convert to gray scale floating point image
            first_image = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
            stacked_image = image
        else:
            # Estimate perspective transform
            s, M = cv2.findTransformECC(cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY), first_image, M, cv2.MOTION_HOMOGRAPHY)
            w, h, _ = image.shape
            # Align image to first image
            image = cv2.warpPerspective(image, M, (h, w))
            align.append(image)

            stacked_image += image
#             cv2.imwrite("aligned{}/aligned{}.png".format(file), image)

            cv2.imshow("aligned", image)
#             cv2.imwrite("output/aligned/",image)
            cv2.waitKey(0)


    stacked_image /= len(file_list)
    stacked_image = (stacked_image*255).astype(np.uint8)

    return align
```

And then I called this function using:

```
align = stackImagesECC(glob.glob(path))
```

Now to perform some functions on this I am trying to read these files from the align variable.

```
#function to detect edges in images
def auto_canny(image, sigma=0.33):
    # Compute the median of the single channel pixel intensities
    img = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    v = np.median(image)


    # Apply automatic Canny edge detection using the computed median
    lower = int(max(0, (1.0 - sigma) * v))
    upper = int(min(255, (1.0 + sigma) * v))
    return cv2.Canny(image, lower, upper)
```

this is the edge detection subroutine for which I want to read the aligned images

```
for file in range(0,len(align)):
        img = cv2.imread(file)
```

Can anyone suggest what am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try `for file in align:` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`align` is already a list of images.  You can just iterate over them to get the images you want:

```
for image in align:
    # Do something with the image
```

However, since you're using a `range` iterator, you can just index directly into `align` to get what you want:

```
for i in range(0, len(align)):
    image = align[i] # Get the ith image
    # Do something with it
```

Because you're returning a list of aligned images, there are things in this function you no longer need.  In particular, you don't need to compute the stacked image.  You probably also don't need to show the images at every iteration.

Therefore:

```
def stackImagesECC(file_list):
    M = np.eye(3, 3, dtype=np.float32)
    first_image = None
    align = []

    for file in file_list:
        image = cv2.imread(file,1).astype(np.float32) / 255
        if first_image is None:
            # convert to gray scale floating point image
            first_image = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        else:
            # Estimate perspective transform
            s, M = cv2.findTransformECC(cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY), first_image, M, cv2.MOTION_HOMOGRAPHY)
            w, h, _ = image.shape
            # Align image to first image
            image = cv2.warpPerspective(image, M, (h, w))
            align.append(image)

    return align
```

Comment: When I am trying to find the edges using canny edge detection it is throwing an error that ```error: (-215) _src.depth() == 0 in function cv::Canny```. what does this mean? does it has anything to do with reading the image?

Comment: `depth == 0` means your image is not grayscale.  I need more information with regards to where you're applying this.  This is not present in your current question.

Comment: On removing the variable M it is throwing an error that ```local variable 'M' referenced before assignment```

Comment: Oh sorry, let me put that back in.  I removed that prematurely.

Comment: I am trying to use these aligned images for edge detection and from that edge detected images I am performing Bitwise_and operation on them

Comment: The Canny Edge detector requires a grayscale input.  Calling `depth()` on a `cv::Mat`, which is what is used internally when you actually call an OpenCV method in Python using a NumPy array as OpenCV is a C++ library, asserting that it's equal to 0 means that the expected input image must be 8-bit unsigned integer (i.e. grayscale).

Comment: I have added the canny function for edge detection for which I needed those images. Is there anything wrong in the function?

Comment: @Happy How exactly are you using the function?

Comment: I am calling it using ```canny = auto_canny(img)```

Comment: @Happy Is it your intent to apply `auto_canny` to every image in `align`?  Do you want to create a new list of images out of this that applies this function to each image individually?  It looks like you're just doing it for one image.  It really helps if you give me more information.  This back and forth is not productive.

Comment: sorry for the inconvenience. So I want these aligned images for edge detection(all of them). Then I am creating a mask for each of the edge detected images. After that I am applying bitwise_and on all the images to extract the white pixel area from each image and put it together on a blank image.

Comment: You need to remove the `cv2.cvtColor` function in your `auto_canny` function as the images are already grayscale.  After just do: `output = [auto_canny(img) for img in align]` to build a list of Canny detection images for each image in `align`.  Also, the reason why it's not working is because even though you converted to grayscale, the variable is stored in `img`, but you used the original input image `image` for the rest of the computation.

Answer (score 0):

`list` is itself a iterator just iterate over it.

```
for file in align:
    # code here...
```

Comment: If you look at the nature of `align` it is already a list of images, not a list of filenames.  Using `cv2.imread` on the actual image itself will result in an error as it expects a string.

Comment: @rayryeng-ReinstateMonica Thanks for poniting out